# Enable .dir-locals.el variables inside just opened buffer

Tags: spacemacs, buffers, directory-local-variables, local-variables

I'm programmtically create a new buffer as a result of shell command

```
(defun jira-ticket-view (&optional jira-ticket)
  "Open Jira Ticket Inside Emacs"
  (interactive)

  (setq jiraURL (get-jira-url))
  (setq jiraPrefix (get-jira-prefix))

  (if (not jira-ticket)
    (setq jira-ticket (get-jira-branch)))

  (setq buffer jira-ticket)
  (let ((b (get-buffer-create buffer)))
    (switch-to-buffer b)
    (markdown-mode)
    (insert (
        concat "## Open in Jira: [" jira-ticket "](" jiraURL "/browse/" jira-ticket ")\n"))
    (insert (
        concat "## Kanban Board: [Open Board](" jiraURL "/browse/" jiraPrefix ")\n"))
    (insert (
        concat "## My Open Issues: [Open Issues](" jiraURL "/projects/" jiraPrefix "/issues/" jira-ticket "?filter=myopenissues)\n\n"))
    (insert (
        shell-command-to-string (
            concat "j view " jira-ticket "  | dos2unix")))))
```

however when I'm in this buffer and trying to run a custom **defun**  that expects some local variables to be set - such command fails with

**list: Symbol’s value as variable is void: jira-project-users**

this is my

#### .dir-locals.el

```
((nil . ((jira-project-prefix . "PROJ")
         (jira-url . "https://domain.atlassian.net/")
         (jira-project-workflow-states . ("Cancel" "Ready For Development" "In Progress" "Ready for Code Review" "Ready for QA" "Back to Backlog" "Stop Development"  "Reopen"  "Verified" "Accepted"))
         (jira-project-users . ("User1" "User2" "User3"))
         (projectile-project-test-cmd . "npm run unit")
         (projectile-globally-ignored-files . ("node_modules"))
         (projectile-register-project-type 'npm '("package.json")
                                           :compile "npm install"
                                           :test "npm test"
                                           :run "npm run start"
                                           :test-suffix "unit.js")
         )))
```

and the following command fails if called in this buffer

**list: Symbol’s value as variable is void: jira-project-users**

```
(defun jira-ticket-assign (username &optional jira-ticket)
  "Assign ticket to a user"
  (interactive
   (let ((completion-ignore-case  t))
     (list (completing-read "Assign to: " jira-project-users nil t)))
  (message "You chose `%s'" username))

  (if (not jira-ticket)
    (setq jira-ticket (get-jira-branch)))

  (setq result (shell-command-to-string (
            concat "j assign " jira-ticket " " username)))
  ;(my-message "Result %s" result)
  ;(message "%s" (propertize result 'face '(:foreground "#A8E4A0"))))
  (message (colorize-ok-error-message result)))
```

Answer (score 4):

As the new buffer is not saved yet it doesn't know where to look for dir-locals.

Have a look at function `hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer` which uses `default-directory` to apply dir-locals to buffers that don't belong to a file.